# How to test for DOM4 Mutation Observers with Modernizr.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modernizr, polyfills, mutation-observers

I'm trying to create a test to detect for [Mutation Observers](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/Detect-DOM-changes-with-Mutation-Observers) using Modernizr.js. On the Modernizer Documentation, [there's a section for testing DOM elements](http://modernizr.com/docs/#prefixeddom) known as prefixes. I tried that using:

```
Modernizr.load({
    test: Modernizr.prefixed('MutationObserver', window),
    yep: ['/js/polyfill_yep.js'],
    nope: ['/js/polyfill_nope.js']
});
```

But obviously, that isn't working. I'm getting a `TypeError: f.bind is not a function` I'm fairly certain the prefixed string isn't MutationObserver, but I don't know what it could be, or even if I'm writing the test correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you run development version so you can get more descriptive error?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a win!

```
Modernizr.load({
    test: MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver,
    yep: '/js/mutations.js',
    nope: '/js/mutation_fallback.js'
});
```